# Docker driver SSH via username and pass

Tags: ssh, drivers, docker

I am a docker newbie and trying to write a docker driver. The driver needs to create a remote host and deploy docker. The problem is that my host does not support SSH keys so I need to login using username and password. So far, I am able to create and manage the host using the driver but docker does not setup on my host. Docker doesn't "know" how to SSH to the host and I don't know how to force docker to use the basic user/pass authentication.

Should I implement an SSH client in my driver or authentication plugin? Or there is a simpler way?

Anyone can give the answer?

Thanks